# Sidebar pagination not shown when sidebar is in single.php

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, navigation

A quick question. So I have created a loop in a new file called `sidebar-extra.php` which **I include via the `header.php` into my `single.php` file**.

**Problem:** when I go to a post (single.php), I can't see this navigation, while I can see it on my homepage, where I also include `sidebar-extra.php`

```
<ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous posts') ?></li>
        <li class="page-item"><?php next_posts_link('Next posts &raquo;') ?></li>
    </ul>
```

Is there a way I can make sure that `my sidebar-extra.php` is showing the post navigation everywhere, including on `single.php`?

**Edit..
This is how it looks like:**

**In sidebar.php**

```
 <?php 
            // the query
            $the_query = new WP_Query(  array( 'posts_per_page' => 25,
                                               'paged' => $paged
                                                ) ); 
            $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

            if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
            ?>
                <!-- pagination here -->
                <!-- the loop -->
                <?php 
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
                ?>
```

**In header.php**

```
  <?php get_sidebar() ?>
```

**In single.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`previous_posts_link()` and `next_posts_link()` are intended for pages that contain a *list* of posts, switching to the next/previous **set of posts** (number depending on the "posts per page" setting)

To switch to the next and previous *single*  post / to use it on single pages, you should use `next_post_link()`  and `previous_post_link()`

(note: "post", not "posts", see also https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_post_link)

Comment: But how exactly? I mean, the sidebar has a list of posts and is being injected into single.php but also other pages. How can I make sure it will serve the navigation for all pages, regardless of whether it's single.php or something else? I mean, if I do what you tell me to do, I don't get the navigation in my sidebar area when I am entering single.php, still...

Comment: Ah - I misunderstood you, sorry! But I don't think it's possible to have a "paginated" list of posts in the sidebar. Among other things that would require AJAX loading into the existing DOM, and I don't think those WP functions are designed for something like that.

Comment: Hmm. You mean this not possible at all? How come it does work on the home page then, when pagination is set in the sidebar that is being injected into index.php via header.php (where the sidebar is being called)?

Comment: I wonder what that looks like? AFAIK, WP pagination only works for the whole page, reloading the whole page. What you describe would rather be loading new content into *part*  of the page (the sidebar), which is only possible with AJAX. Are you using a plugin or any particular script for that?

Comment: I have edited my post with the structure of how I am using it. It's nothing special, but it gives you an insight...